# No detecta mi condicion

Tags: javascript, html, css, css3, aplicación-web

Estoy creando una pagina que generada pseudnumeros aleatorios por el algoritmo de multiplicador constante, tengo una condicion que no me respeta la condicion, ya le movi de todas forma y segun logica esta bien  pero al momento de hacer la interaccion no me lo respeta.
Ejemplo si coloco como semilla a 7777 y como constante a 1111, en la interaccion 11 me da 589941 el cual son menos de 8 digitos, entonces con esta condicionme deberia agregar dos ceros al inicio, siendo 00589941 y tomando como valor semilla 5899, pero no me lo hace este es es la condicion
adjunto imagen [image: En esta interaccion me debe agregar dos ceros al inicio, y tomar los 4 valores de en medio, siendo 0.5899]

adjunto mi codigo, Porfavor y de antemano muchas gracias i

```js
var semilla = 0,
  constante = 0,
  n = 0;

var tb = document.getElementById('table');

var in1 = document.getElementById('semilla');

var in2 = document.getElementById('constante');

var in3 = document.getElementById('n');

function NewSemilla(semilla, mult) {

  var tam = mult.toString().length;
  var dif = 0;
  var aux = "";

  if (tam > semilla.toString().length) {

    if (tam % 2 != 0 && semilla.toString().length % 2 == 0) { // el tamano no es par y la semilla es par
      //1212 1212 1212
      aux = "0" + mult.toString();
      tam = aux.length;
      dif = tam - semilla.toString().length;
      dif = parseInt(dif / 2);
      aux = aux.substr(dif, semilla.toString().length);
      //console.log(aux);
      return aux;

    } else if (tam % 2 != 0 && semilla.toString().length % 2 != 0) { // el tamano no es par y la semilla no es par
      //123 123 122

      aux = mult.toString();
      tam = aux.length;
      dif = tam - semilla.toString().length;
      dif = parseInt(dif / 2);
      aux = aux.substr(dif, semilla.toString().length);
      // console.log(aux);
      return aux;

    } else if (tam % 2 == 0 && semilla.toString().length % 2 == 0) { // el tamano es par y la semilla es par
      //123 1231 221

      aux = mult.toString();
      tam = aux.length;
      dif = tam - semilla.toString().length;
      dif = parseInt(dif / 2);
      aux = aux.substr(dif, semilla.toString().length);
      //console.log(aux);
      return aux;
    } else if (tam % 2 == 0 && semilla.toString().length % 2 != 0) { // el tamano es par y la semilla no es par
      //123 123 1220

      aux = "0" + mult.toString();
      tam = aux.length;
      dif = tam - semilla.toString().length;
      dif = parseInt(dif / 2);
      aux = aux.substr(dif, semilla.toString().length);
      //console.log(aux);
      return aux;
    } else {
      console.log('ya no entra');
      return semilla;
    }
  } else
    return mult;


}

function Evaluate() {

  let rn = parseInt(tb.rows.length) - 1;
  while (rn >= 0) {
    document.getElementById("table").deleteRow(rn);
    rn--;
  }


  aux = in1.value;
  semilla = parseInt(aux);
  aux = in2.value;
  constante = parseInt(aux);
  aux = in3.value;
  n = parseInt(aux);

  if (!isNaN(semilla) && !isNaN(constante) && !isNaN(n)) {

    var array = new Array(n);
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++)
      array[i] = new Array(4);


    array[0][0] = 0;
    array[0][1] = parseInt(semilla) * constante;
    array[0][2] = constante;
    array[0][3] = semilla;
    array[0][4] = '0.' + NewSemilla(semilla, parseInt(semilla) * constante);
    semilla = NewSemilla(semilla, parseInt(semilla) * constante);
    //console.log(array[0][4]);


    for (var i = 1; i < n; i++) {
      array[i][0] = i;
      array[i][1] = parseInt(semilla) * constante;
      array[i][2] = constante;
      array[i][3] = semilla;
      array[i][4] = '0.' + NewSemilla(semilla, parseInt(semilla) * constante);
      semilla = NewSemilla(semilla, parseInt(semilla) * constante);

      // Agregamos ceros al inicio si el resultado tiene menos de 8 cifras
      if (array[i][4].length < 8) {
        array[i][4] = "0".repeat(8 - array[i][4].length) + array[i][4];
      }
      // Redondeamos el número a 4 cifras decimales
      array[i][4] = parseFloat(array[i][4]).toFixed(4);

      // Imprimimos el resultado en consola
      console.log(`Iteración ${i}: ${array[i][4]}`);
    }

    tb.className = "table table-dark";

    // Creando la tabla para mostrar los datos
    var thead = document.createElement('thead');
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');


    var i = document.createElement('th');
    var yi = document.createElement('th');
    var a = document.createElement('th');
    var xi = document.createElement('th');
    var ri = document.createElement('th');

    var text1 = document.createTextNode("i");
    var text2 = document.createTextNode("yi");
    var text3 = document.createTextNode("a");
    var text4 = document.createTextNode("Xi");
    var text5 = document.createTextNode("R");

    i.appendChild(text1);
    yi.appendChild(text2);
    a.appendChild(text3);
    xi.appendChild(text4);
    ri.appendChild(text5);

    tr.appendChild(i);
    tr.appendChild(yi);
    tr.appendChild(a);
    tr.appendChild(xi);
    tr.appendChild(ri);

    thead.appendChild(tr);
    tb.appendChild(thead);

    var tbody = document.createElement('tbody');
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      tr = document.createElement('tr');

      var td1 = document.createElement('td');
      var td2 = document.createElement('td');
      var td3 = document.createElement('td');
      var td4 = document.createElement('td');
      var td5 = document.createElement('td');


      text1 = document.createTextNode(array[i][0]);
      text2 = document.createTextNode(array[i][1]);
      text3 = document.createTextNode(array[i][2]);
      text4 = document.createTextNode(array[i][3]);
      text5 = document.createTextNode(array[i][4]);

      td1.appendChild(text1);
      td2.appendChild(text2);
      td3.appendChild(text3);
      td4.appendChild(text4);
      td5.appendChild(text5);
      tr.appendChild(td1);
      tr.appendChild(td2);
      tr.appendChild(td3);
      tr.appendChild(td4);
      tr.appendChild(td5);

      tbody.appendChild(tr);
    }
    tb.appendChild(tbody);
  } else
    alert('Hay algo mal con las entradas de datos');


}

function clean() {
  // Limpiar campos de entrada
  document.getElementById("semilla").value = "";
  document.getElementById("constante").value = "";
  document.getElementById("n").value = "";

  // Limpiar tabla de resultados
  var table = document.getElementById("table");
  table.innerHTML = "";
}
```

```css
body {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #30cfd0 0%, #330867 100%);
  height: 1300px;
  color: beige;
}

.bar {
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
}

.row {
  width: 950px;
  height: 150px;
  padding-left: 300px;
}

.txt {
  font-size: 29px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
}

.txtm {
  font-size: 29px;
  margin-top: 8px;
}

input {
  width: 200px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size: 20px;
  border: 3px solid black;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.lbl {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  font-size: 600px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}

.text {
  font-size: 29px;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  font-size: 29px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.btn01 button {
  background-color: #009688;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0px 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.btn01 button:hover {
  background-color: #00796b;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.result {
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

.lbl1 {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.about {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
  border-radius: 10px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/multiplicadorConstante.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <title>Multiplicador Constante</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="bar container my-5">
    <h1>Multiplicador Constante</h1>
    <h3>Algoritmo</h3>

  </div>
  <div class="txt container">
    <div class="row  g-2 py-3 mx-5">
      <div class="col-6 text-white">
        <label for="semilla" class="col-form-label">Ingrese la semilla X<sub>0</sub></label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <input type="number" id="semilla" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="txtm container">
    <div class="row  g-2 py-3 mx-5">
      <div class="col-6 text-white">
        <label for="semilla" class="col-form-label">Ingrese la semilla X<sub>1</sub></label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <input type="number" id="constante" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="txtm container">
    <div class="row  g-2 py-3 mx-5">
      <div class="col-6 text-white">
        <label for="semilla" class="col-form-label">Ingrese cuantos resultados quiere visualizar</label>
      </div>
      <div class="col-6">
        <input type="number" id="n" class="form-control">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="btn01 container py-5 text-center">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" onclick="Evaluate()">Calcular</button>
    <button id="limpiar-btn" class="btn btn-outline-light btn-lg" onclick="clean()">Limpiar</button>
  </div>
  <div class="result container text-center ">
    <table id="table" class="lbl1 "></table>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-U1DAWAznBHeqEIlVSCgzq+c9gqGAJn5c/t99JyeKa9xxaYpSvHU5awsuZVVFIhvj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="./assets/Js/multiplicadorConstante.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La verdad es que no entendí tu código, creo que es execivamente complejo. Evidentemente el problema está en como haces el substring. En todo caso, este algoritmo es muy sencillo, te dejo una demo

```js
function calcular(){
  let semillaInput = document.getElementById("semilla").valueAsNumber;
  let X=[];
  X.push(semillaInput); //X0
 
  let A = document.getElementById("constante").valueAsNumber;
  let veces = document.getElementById("n").valueAsNumber;
    
  tabla.innerHTML ="";
    
  for(let i=0; i<veces; i++)
  {
      let AX = A * X[i]; 
      X.push( Number(String(AX).padStart(8,"0").substring(2,6))); //Xi+1

      let r = X[i+1]/10000;

      tabla.innerHTML +=`<tr>
        <td>${i}</td>
        <td>${AX}</td>
        <td>${A}</td>
        <td>${X[i]}</td>
        <td>${r}</td>
      </tr>`;
  }
    
}
```

```html
<label>semilla </label>
<input type="number" id="semilla" >
<br>
<label>Constante</label>
<input type="number" id="constante" >
<br>
<label>Resultados</label>
<input type="number" id="n" >
<br>
<button onclick="calcular()">Calcular</button>
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td>N° Pseudoalatoreo</td>
    <tr>
      <td>i</td>
      <td>A*Xi</td>
      <td>A</td>
      <td>Semilla Xi</td>
      <td>ri</td>
    <tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody id="tabla" >
  <tbody>
</table>
```

Concejos:

1.- Usar [substring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substring) en vez de [substr](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr), este último está obsoleto. La diferencias entre ambos es que en `substring` los argumentos son *`(indice_inicio,indice_final)`* y con `substr` son *`(indice_inicio,largo)`*

2.- Preferir usar siempre `Number` por sobre `parseInt`

3.- Los cero a la izquierda se pueden agregar usando [padstart](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/global_objects/string/padstart)

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano, Esta mucho mas entedible tu codigo. Gracias hermano